# weblogic12c admin console doesn't start

Tags: certificate, admin, keystore, weblogic12c, kss

Lately our server admin console not starting and do not have Error on Admin.out file. Just stop after this sentence "Loading trusted certificates from the kss keystore file kss://system/trust.> " Can someone help me ?

<2015-03-23 11:13:54.349/29.679 Oracle Coherence GE 12.1.2.0.0  (thread=[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', member=n/a): UnicastUdpSocket failed to set receive buffer size to 16 packets (1MB); actual size is 12%, 2 packets (127KB). Consult your OS documentation regarding increasing the maximum socket buffer size. Proceeding with the actual value may cause sub-optimal performance.> 
    <2015-03-23 11:13:54.350/29.680 Oracle Coherence GE 12.1.2.0.0  (thread=[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', member=n/a): PreferredUnicastUdpSocket failed to set receive buffer size to 1444 packets (2MB); actual size is 6%, 90 packets (127KB). Consult your OS documentation regarding increasing the maximum socket buffer size. Proceeding with the actual value may cause sub-optimal performance.> 
Mar 23, 2015 11:13:56 AM oracle.ods.virtualization.engine.util.VDELogger info
INFO: Notification sent for Mapping config object reloaded
Mar 23, 2015 11:13:57 AM oracle.ods.virtualization.engine.util.VDELogger info
INFO: Notification sent for Mapping config object reloaded
Mar 23, 2015 11:13:58 AM oracle.dms.event.config.EventConfig buildEventConfig
INFO: DMS-58081: The FlightRecorderDestination (id=JFRDestination) can not function in this environment because although the JVMs flight recorder feature is present it is inactive. Platform:WebLogic, VM:{'name'='Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM', 'version'='24.75-b04', 'spec-version'='1.7'}.
Cause: The JVM has a flight recorder feature but the flight recorder feature is not active.
Action: Review the JVMs flight recorder settings and if you wish DMS to contribute data to the flight recorder then enable the flight recorder feature. This can be accomplished on some JVMs by including these command line options: -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder. In the meantime the event route involving the JFRDestination will be disabled.

**Security BEA-090171  Loading the identity certificate and private key stored under the alias DemoIdentity from the kss keystore file kss://system/demoidentity.
Mar 23, 2015 11:14:25 AM EET Notice  Security  BEA-090169  Loading trusted certificates from the kss keystore file kss://system/trust.**

Answer (score 0):

You mention your admin console does not start, I guess you mean your admin server does not start and hence your admin console does not come up.

Did you check your admin.log file, the .out file does not always have the most verbose output. Consider lowering the logging level (you will have to edit the config.xml manually for this).

If you have another domain that runs fine, compare the sequence of log output between these 2 domains. If you find out what the next line of log should be which is missing in your failing server, that could also give a clue on what could be happening.

Enabling debug on startup could be another option, but you will again have to manually edit the config for this.

Comment: I compared two different domains but found nothing. I also check the admin.log file and nothing come out from this too. I don't know what changed but it doesn't give me this error on start-up anymore.

Comment: And something interesting, normally it should load the jks file not kss file, right ?

Comment: Yes it did seem odd, but I didnt comment as I am not aware of your domain. Check your previous log for the same domain and see what it says for the same line - "Loading trusted certificates from the kss keystore file kss://system/trust.> " If its jks, which it should be, then you might want to revert back to a backed up config.xml file, wls automatically keeps config backup

Comment: Actually it happened after we upgraded to weblogic 12c and adf 12c . weblogic 12.1.2 version has so many bugs. For workaround soluotion I shutdown all jvm including admin server and deleted the pending folders. After that I activated it. But we need a permanent solution. Other wise we'll consider upgrade weblogic 12.1.3.

By the way, if you know another workaround let me know.  thx anyway.